# Laptop webcam cabling

Tags: wiring, camera, laptop

I am currently offsite and without my trusty tools. 
I am converting an integrated webcam from an old Asus X52J laptop into an USB webcam but the colors of the wiring kinda threw me off.

**Here's a couple of images:**
[image: First]
[image: Second]

How do i match them to a standard black-red-green-white USB cable?
Webcam part no. is 04g620008630 0420-006a000 11261025542 1211

Comment: Assuming engineers of the past used color codes is a bad idea

Comment: I'm sorry, what??

Comment: From the twisting pair, I would assume Brown and Red are D= and D- (not necessarily in this order).

Comment: That means orange is positive and black negative? And then yellow\lime...

Comment: There are five cables. V+ and ground should be obvious on the board by any capacitor or large traces. D+ and D- will be two traces routed identically. There is a fifth wire typically not found in usb. And as for V+, it might not be 5V it could be 3.3v

Comment: The device is tiny, there's no noteworthy feature that sticks out at a glance. Does everybody agree on the tentative answer ricardomenzer gave? The twisted ones are D+ and D-, orange positive and black negative, leaving yellow\lime as the unconnected one.

Comment: Why are you putting the solution in the question? [se] is a question and answer network. We expect seperate questions and answers. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Because my question was put on hold by the nice people @electronics.stackexchange so i could not solve it. NOW that i've been moved i can actually answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLUTION:

It is a 5V camera but the polarity is inverted:

- (USB cable)    <---> (Webcam)
- RED (+5v)    <---> BLACK
- BLACK (GND)  <---> ORANGE
- WHITE (D+)   <---> BROWN
- GREEN (D-)   <---> RED
- nothing    <---> YELLOW

Then it gets correctly detected:

```
usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=13d3, idProduct=5130
usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
usb 2-1.2: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
Linux video capture interface: v2.00
uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (13d3:5130)
input: USB 2.0 Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/input/input27
usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

grzywomat's answer is accurate (D+ and D- are swapped) but this seems to need 3.3V, I did it was straight 5v and it got quite hot, I put a 3.3V regulator on it and it doesn't get too hot anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Actually for me the order of `data` pins is the other way round, i.e. standard for USB.
Nevertheless thank you, as your identification was very helpful.
(After soldering as per your schematics, I decided to reverse data pins, as power draw seemed fine (power pins not terribly wrong), and dmesg returned some “cannot enumerate” message which looked to me like just `data` pins being wrong..)