# issue laptop webcam connection via USB

Tags: usb, laptop, webcam, camera, wiring

hi i have an old laptop webcam of ASUS K52J model that I want to use by connecting it via a USB cable. I disassembled my laptop and connected the webcam using a USB cable with four colors: black, red, green, and white. The webcam has five color wires: brown, yellow, orange, red, and black. I followed a wiring guide from [Laptop webcam cabling](https://superuser.com/questions/975334/laptop-webcam-cabling) that matched the colors of the webcam wires. However i success to connect it but i am facing an issue where sometimes the webcam connects and sometimes it does not. I have also installed the webcam driver, but I am getting a "USB not recognized" error. Interestingly, when I touch the wires of the USB cable, the webcam sometimes starts working.

The webcam model is aiovs021000 0b. Attached are some images for reference.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully connect my webcam via USB.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d87o.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHX1a.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM0kT.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t7mD.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b789S.png